# ListView update

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have two **activities** with ListView. This two activitises have individual layout-file. First have myListView01, second have myListView02. How to update listView's adapters?
I do so:

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView01);
myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item01, R.id.label, array01);  
list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

I remove some items from the array01 and I need to update my listView without this elements.
But this solution to **ListActivity** does not work:

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

my code:

```
package ...;
import ...;
public class Class01 extends Activity
{
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    ArrayList<String> array01 = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.layout01);

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list01);
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item01, R.id.label, array01);  

        list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    public void onListItemClick (ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {  
        array01 = deleteElementByPosition(array01, position);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //does not work
    }  
    public void deleteElementByPosition()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Always a good idea is to use loaders

Comment: What? How does it relate to the ListView?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: I don't need load anything. Where in this example is the adapter's update?

Comment: Too cumbersome solution, but thanks.

Comment: When you set an adapter to a list, it gets updated itself... or what exactly is your question? elaborate your problem a little more

Comment: I remove some items from the array01 and I need to update my listView without this elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set [onItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) for your `ListView`.
Extend your `Class01` from `ListActivity`. `Activity` class doesn't have `onListItemClick()` method so it is never invoked. Or set your listener with [setOnItemClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) for your `ListView`.